# Zend framework 2 - Orm Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

`Zend framework` 2 With  `Orm Doctrine 2` have any tools to generate the Entity, module, controller, view and Form like `YII` tools `GII` and cake `PHP` tools `cakebake`.

Comment: have you looked at the doctrine tool? ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module you can use orm:convert-mapping and orm:generate-entities to create entitys. Use zftool to create module & controller.

Comment: @YRM thanks, but i was already know about entities generator but this generator is not generate accurate entities and also populate function. And also these entities only used fetching data from table but when we are insert the data in table then it's gives error of foreign key(means foreign key value alway's show null) -SPR7